# Vaadin Designer Not an Editable Custom Component

Tags: java, web, ide, vaadin, designer

New to using Vaadin and I wanted to use the designer to modify the default page given when creating a vaadin project.

However I keep getting this error: 'Could not open design view: Failed to parse visually editable class caused by Not an editable CustomComponent'

The code is as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("timekeeper")
public class TimekeeperUI extends UI {

    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = TimekeeperUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);
    }

}
```

I think I have the xulrunner installed correctly as I'm not getting this error when I start up eclipse.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was an issue with the Service pack of eclipse I was using. Took me a while to get redirected to the page after googling for ages that told me this.

Comment: Could you perhaps share more details of the solution to your problem? This will help others in future.

Comment: There's not much to the solution, I had to go download the newer version of the service pack. I was using Luna SR1 so I downloaded SR2, then resetup my environment

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen it explicitly stated anywhere yet, but I'm 90% sure [the editor](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/eclipse.editor.html) works with descendants of `com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent`. Thus, my suggestion is to create a new CustomComponent/Vaadin Composite as described [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/eclipse.composite-new.html), edit it visually and add an instance of it to your UI.

P.S. If you go and do some manual changes and still want to keep it editor-parseable, you should pay attention to at least the following (from what I can recall now):

- `@Autogenerated` fields and methods
- alignments it generates as `new Alignment(34)` instead of `Alignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT`
- labels `ContentMode.HTML (not 100% sure but I remember setting these in the constructors instead of the autogenerated methods)